# SSRS Date Parameter Input switching between UK and US Date Formats

Tags: date, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, business-intelligence, ssrs-2012

My report takes two parameters, `@FromDate` and `@ToDate`.

I want to simply take these and pass them into SQL Query limiting the results between those values. The issue arises in configuring the input for these parameters. The today value is displayed as expected and desired, *en-GB*, **dd/MM/yyyy**. If I select this value, it changes in the date display box to *en-US* **MM/dd/yyyy**.

If it remained in the *en-US* format this would not be an issue to deal with but the error that start happening is that when I hit View Report, the format switches from **MM/dd/yyyy** in the parameter to **dd/MM/yyyy** and changes every time I re-run the report.

I have changed the Language of the report and fields to *en-GB* with no change. I have also looked in the report **.rsd** to see whether there is any way of formatting the value seen but with no result.

Comment: have you tried to use `Format` or `Custom Date` format? also why don't you try to convert it from `SQL Query` side?

Answer (score 1):

You can add parameters for the Dataset and apply conversion to report parameters.
[SSRS Query Parameters](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3453/sql-server-reporting-services-reports-with-optional-query-parameters/)

For example:

Your **report** paramters are `@FromDate` and `@ToDate`.

Add two **Dataset** parameters: `@queryFromDate` and `@queryToDate` 
 apply expression to value: `Format(CDate(Parameters!@FromDate.Value), "dd/MM/yyyy")`  and  `Format(CDate(Parameters!@ToDate.Value), "dd/MM/yyyy")`

SQL query will look like:

```
select ... from ... where [field_date] between @queryFromDate and @queryToDate
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your suggestion. Sadly it seems to be an issue even before the parameters can have an expression applied leading me to believe that the MM and dd parts of the date were populated incorrectly before reaching the expression which then would not run as the value was greater 12 in the MM field. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Hopefully the late comment helps someone. This suggestion worked for me, but it's worth pointing out that formatting your dates using dd/MM/yyyy still leaves things open to interpretation. I got reliable results only when formatting with yyyy-MM-dd instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need change the calendar settings on PC or Server where your report are rendered. Go to "Control Panel" => "Region and Language " = > Change "Format" to "English (United Kingdom) " . 
The report use Windows settings only for parameter input , else dates rendered on report are depend by SSRS and SQL Query.

Comment: I looked into the calendar settings on my PC, where the reports are rendered, and the format was English(United Kingdom). I checked the format for the visual studio, the report and the fields and they all hold to English (United Kingdom).